# postgres aggregate not showing rows where LEFT JOIN table has nulls

Tags: postgresql, null, aggregate, string-aggregation

I have a table that list email addressed for a member and has a boolean is_selected. The idea is that only one should be selected. I am joining the table to itself with a where clause on is_selected. I want to

```
string_agg(u.email, ',')
```

to show all the unselected emails in one column/row in a view.

[Here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/74d5c).

My problem is that I can't get the view to work in cases where there are no entries that are unselected.

sql fiddle is having issues today so:

```
CREATE TABLE member_email
  (
    member integer NOT NULL, -- reference to another table
    email character varying(150) NOT NULL,
    is_selected boolean NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(member,email)
  );

INSERT INTO member_email 
    (member,email,is_selected) 
    VALUES 
        (2,'dax@example.com',TRUE),
        (2,'oldemail@example.com',FALSE),
        (2,'prevemail@example.com',FALSE),
        (3,'rick@example.com',TRUE),
        (3,'richard@example.com',FALSE),
        (4,'bob@example.com',TRUE);

CREATE VIEW v_member_email AS 
    SELECT s.member
    ,s.email as selected_email
    ,string_agg(u.email, ',') as unselected_email 
    FROM member_email s 
    LEFT JOIN member_email u 
        ON s.member = u.member 
    WHERE s.is_selected = TRUE 
        AND u.is_selected = FALSE 
    GROUP BY s.member,s.email 
    ORDER BY member;

SELECT * FROM v_member_email;

-- where is bob@example.com in result?
```

Comment: `... AND u.is_selected = FALSE ...` . Since you are testing an attribute from the left-joined u table, the leftjoin effectively degrades into a plain join. You could use ` ... AND u.is_selected IS DISTINCT FROM True ...` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/74d5c/4)

If the condition on the right side is put in the `where` clause you transform the `left join` into an `inner join`. Just move it to the join condition:

```
select
    s.member
    ,s.email as selected_email
    ,string_agg(u.email, ',') as unselected_email 
from
    member_email s 
    left join
    member_email u on
        s.member = u.member
        and not u.is_selected
where s.is_selected
group by s.member,s.email 
order by member;
```